# Having "Type 'ForwardedRef<HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type 'Ref<InputRef> | undefined' "error while creating a reusable Input component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a reusable Input component with RectJs and Typescript. while creating it I'm getting this error. what is the Typescript way to fix this error?

I'm using "react": "^18.2.0", and "typescript": "4.8.4"

**My code:**

```
import React, { InputHTMLAttributes, ForwardRefRenderFunction } from 'react'
import { Input } from 'antd';

interface InputProps extends InputHTMLAttributes<HTMLInputElement> {
    name: string;
    label: string;
    ref: string;
   
}

 const InputTextField: ForwardRefRenderFunction<HTMLInputElement, InputProps> = ({ name, label, ...props }, ref) => {
    
    return (
        <label >
            {label}
            <Input
                 
                className='formInput'
                {...props}
                name={name}
 >               ref={ref}
                />            
        </label>
    );
};


const InputField = React.forwardRef(InputTextField);

export default InputField
```

**Error:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In docs not only once said about 'any' and 'ts-ignore'.
ForwardRef they are use with 'any'.

https://beta-pro.ant.design/docs/type-script
https://ant.design/docs/react/use-custom-date-library#timepickertsx

Similar problem was with DatePicker

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/33417

I think this is a bug. You can fix this with 'as any'.

```
<Input class Name="form Input" {...props} name={name} ref={ref as any}  />
```

And you can create PR to antd repository to fix this bug)